# What is the difference between AJAX API and Axios of NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Do libraries like Axios and Request for NodeJS fulfill exactly what an AJAX request does?

I feel like it does the exact same thing except from the server side? I've never used AJAX and when I built a data scraping program using API calls a co-worker asked me about it and I told him I had no clue what it was.

So after watching a quick video I feel like those libraries do the exact same thing as AJAX? Just asking here for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Axios and Request do HTTP(S) requests.

AJAX is "a set of web technologies to With Ajax, web applications can send and retrieve data from a server asynchronously [via HTTP(S)]". [~ Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

So yes, both things are somehow related.

Comment: Thank you sir Jonas

Comment: Also, node.js is a javascript runtime environment. It is like an engine for running your javascript.